# npm start failing daemon not working

Tags: node.js, sqlite

So I want to start playing with the google sheets API. I have followed the instructions as indicated here:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/sheets-api/#2

I have installed node.js & git (fresh installs)

I then pulled the files from git, and then ran npm install - no problems so far.

Then I ran npm start and got the following error

```
$ npm start

sheets-api-codelab@1.0.0 start C:\Users\sbala\Projects\sheets-api\start
nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 1.17.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
C:\Users\sbala\Projects\sheets-api\start\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\connection-manager.js:27
    throw err;
    ^
Error: \\?\C:\Users\sbala\Projects\sheets- 
api\start\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v57-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node is not a valid Win32 application. 
\\?\C:\Users\sbala\Projects\sheets- api\start\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v57-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:681:18) at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sbala\Projects\sheets-api\start\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:4:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at new ConnectionManager (C:\Users\sbala\Projects\sheets-api\start\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\connection-manager.js:22:16)
at new SqliteDialect (C:\Users\sbala\Projects\sheets-api\start\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\index.js:12:28)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I've tried finding a solution, but it seems the app can crash for many reasons, adn I cannot seem to find one that helps me. I have tried re doing npm install, and npm start multiple times, and I keep getting the same error at the sqlitedialect line. As such I can only surmise that something has gone wrong with sqlite?

this is my npm version

```
$ npm version
{ 'sheets-api-codelab': '1.0.0',
  npm: '6.0.1',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  cldr: '32.0',
  http_parser: '2.8.0',
  icu: '60.1',
  modules: '57',
  nghttp2: '1.25.0',
  node: '8.11.1',
  openssl: '1.0.2o',
  tz: '2017c',
  unicode: '10.0',
  uv: '1.19.1',
  v8: '6.2.414.50',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }
```

and my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "sheets-api-codelab",
  "description": "In this codelab, you'll learn how to integrate the Google Sheets API into an application to provide custom reporting.",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "author": {
    "name": "Eric Koleda",
    "email": "ekoleda+devrel@googlers.com"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/googlecodelabs/sheets-api",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "sequelize": "^3.21.0",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.9.1"
  }
}
```

Server.js file here

```
    #!/usr/bin/env node

/*
  Copyright 2016 Google, Inc.

  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more contributor
  license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with this work for
  additional information regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this
  file to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
  the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
  WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
  License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
  the License.
*/

'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('./app');
var http = require('http');
var models = require('./models');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Load the models.
 */
models.sequelize.sync().then(function() {
  /**
   * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
   */
  server.listen(port);
  server.on('error', onError);
  server.on('listening', onListening);
});

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */
function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */
function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string' ? 'Pipe ' + port : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */
function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + addr : 'port ' + addr.port;
  console.log('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: please add your server.js file you add your package.json file instead

Comment: @NaorTedgi here you go, thanks